# FullCalendar dayClick doesn't work until month is changed

Tags: fullcalendar

FullCalendar dayClick doesn't work in my project until the user either goes back or ahead one month then back to the present month. I inherited this project and have no previous experience with calendar functions so I'm not sure where to start, except to post the markup associated with one of the calendars. I'm rather new to StackOverflow so let me know if I need to post any other details. Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="PersonalCalendar.ascx.cs" Inherits="Controls_Events_PersonalCalendar" %>
<link id="lnkCSSFiles" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/fullcalendar.css" runat="server" />
<div class="rightCol">
    <div class="search masked formWhole">
        <label for="searchBox">
            Search</label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" CssClass="text" runat="server" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" CssClass="button" Text="Search" OnClick="btnSearch_Click"
            runat="server" />
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <asp:ListView ID="lsvSearch" runat="server">
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <h3>
                Search Results</h3>
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceHolder" runat="server" />
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="eventList">
                <a href="<%#((EventsWrapper)Container.DataItem).URL %>" class="eventTitle">
                    <%# ((EventsWrapper)Container.DataItem).Title%></a> <span class="eventDate">
                        <%# ((EventsWrapper)Container.DataItem).StartDate%></span> <span class="eventLocation">
                            in
                            <%# ((EventsWrapper)Container.DataItem).City%></span> <a class="more" href="<%#((EventsWrapper)Container.DataItem).URL %>">
                                View Event &raquo;</a>
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
</div>
<div id="genWidget" class="calendarWidget" runat="server">
    <div id="calendar"> 
    </div>
</div>
<!--end Calendar Widget-->
<asp:Literal ID="litJavaScripts" Text="~/tft-js/core/fullcalendar.js,~/tft-js/core/jquery.dateformat.js,~/tft-js/jquery.tools.min.js" runat="server" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    function outputAMPM(d) {
            var date = new Date(d);
            h = d.getHours();
            if (h < 12)
                return "AM";
            return "PM";
        }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#calendar").fullCalendar({
            <% if (m_Year.HasValue){ %>year: <%= m_Year.Value %>,<%} %>
            <% if (m_Month.HasValue){ %>month: <%= m_Month.Value - 1 %>,<%} %>
            events: '<%= ResolveClientUrl(Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath) + (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString.ToString()) ? "?" + Request.QueryString.ToString() : "") %>',
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next title',
                center: '',
                right: ''
            },
            aspectRatio: 1.1,
            titleLength: <%= TitleLength %>,
            weekSelectURL: '<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/events.aspx") + m_DaylessQueryString + (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(m_DaylessQueryString) ? "&" : "?") %>',
            weekMode: 'variable',
            timeFormat: 'H(:mm)', 
            eventRender: function(event, element) {
                element.append('<div class="eventPopup"><div class="popupWrapper"><span class="title">'+ event.title + '</span><span>' + $.format.date(event.start, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm") + outputAMPM(event.start) + '</span><span class="address">' + event.Address1+ '<br />' + event.Address2+ '<br />' + event.City + ', ' +event.State +' ' + event.Zip + '</span>' + '<a class="more" href="'+event.url +'">'+event.url +'</a><a class="more" href="all-events.aspx">View More</a><div class="clearfix"><div class="addthis_toolbox"><a class="addthis_button_facebook" addthis:url="'+ event.url +'" addthis:title="'+ event.title + '"></a><a class="addthis_button_tweet" tw:count="none"></a><a class="addthis_button_google_plusone" <%= "g:plusone:count=\"false\"" %>></a></div></div></div></div>');
            },
      eventAfterRender: function(event, element,view){
       setTimeout(function(){
        $('div.fc-event > a').tooltip().dynamic();
                $('div.fc-event').hover(function() {
                        $(this).addClass('hoveredEvent');
                    },
                    function() {
                        $(this).removeClass('hoveredEvent');
                    }
                );
       },1000);
      }
        });
        $(".fc-day-number").each(function(){
            var num = $(this).find("a").html();
            $(this).html(num);
        });
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-5098045873d5139d"></script>
```

Comment: Anyone? Something I thought of is to click the buttons through Javascript commands but that didn't work:

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('next');
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('prev');

Need suggestions, please. I don't see why the days aren't clickable in the calendar in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered this problem when i used it. It was due to the code not written in $(document).ready(function(){}). Since you have done that try specifying a default view. to it. 
If possible create a http://www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: Thank you. Through some trial and error, I found that the problem was in the _eventAfterRender_ and _.fc-day-number_ functions. Once I commented those out, the days were "clickable."

Please tell me what jsfiddle does and how to operate it. The page I saw at the site didn't seem very clear to me.

Comment: sure. You can check this out   http://css-tricks.com/seriously-just-make-a-jsfiddle/